# C# how to correctly override base class property in children class?

Tags: c#, inheritance, polymorphism

Could somebody tell me please, how in children class correctly override property declared in parent class?
I am trying to override "Tasks" property. In child class it should return list of items of type "ICheckListTask".Part of code:

Parent class:

```
internal class CBaseTaskList : IBaseTaskList
{
    protected List<IBaseTask> _tasks = new List<IBaseTask>();

    virtual protected List<IBaseTask> Tasks
    {
        get { return _tasks; }
        set { _tasks = value; }
    }

    public virtual IBaseTask this[int index]
    {
        get { return Tasks[index]; }
        set { Tasks[index] = value; }
    }

    public virtual void Add(IBaseTask newTask)
    {
        Tasks.Add(newTask);
    }
```

Children class:

```
internal class CCheckListTaskList : CBaseTaskList, ICheckListTaskList
{
    override protected List<ICheckListTask> Tasks
    {
        get { return (List<ICheckListTask>)_tasks; }
        set { Tasks = value; }
    }

    public void WhereIsDone()
    {
        Tasks = new List<ICheckListTask>(Tasks.Where(x => x.IsDone == true));
    }
```

In children class I get error what type of CCheckListTaskList.Task must be not "List<ICheckListTask>", but "List<IBaseTask>".
How to correctly do what I want to do?

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use "new" instead of "override"

Comment: Sorry, this not helped a lot, I anyway have error, what List<IBaseTask> can't be transformed into List<ICheckListTask>

Comment: Does ICheckListTask inherit IBaseTask?

Comment: Yes
    ```internal interface ICheckListTask : IBaseTask
    {
        bool IsDone { get; set; }
        IDatePeriod TaskDatePeriod { get; set; }
    }```

Comment: Would you explain how you want to use these classes? And at which line the error occurs?

Comment: Error occurs at "override protected List<ICheckListTask> Tasks"
I want to have possibility to use List of base class items with interface IBaseTask to store children class items with interface ICheckListTask. Functions added in CCheckListTaskList need object of ICheckListTask to work, because IBaseTask does not have IsDone and some other properties. Same time, there should no new lists appear (I tried to shadow base class list with "new", but it is not working well), so this list must be common for both IBaseTaskList and ICheckListTaskList

Comment: Well, maybe I found where problem can be,
I am using a bit outdated .net framework version (4.8), what can have no support for some modern features, now I will try to update and take a look.

Comment: I updated but this not helped...

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).